# Converting dgCMatrix to data frame and getting error in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to convert a matrix to a data frame using as.data.frame() and I am getting an error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(coef) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")’ to a data.frame
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Matrix class:

```
class(coef)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to regular matrix and then use `as.data.frame`

```
library(Matrix)
as.data.frame.matrix(Matrix(0, 3, 2))
```

-output

```
  V1 V2
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  0  0
```

Instead of

```
> as.data.frame(Matrix(0, 3, 2))
Error in as.data.frame.default(Matrix(0, 3, 2)) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")’ to a data.frame
```